# Code won't execute after recordset returns using if-statement

Tags: asp-classic, recordset

Can anyone help me explain the following problem

In a SQL-query I get info about the occurrence of an id from another table.
Everything works here and I show a crucial snippet below

```
    set rsRecordCount = Cn.execute(mysql_query)
    dim cnt
    cnt = rsRecordCount("TotalRecords")
    response.write("cnt " & cnt & " id = " & id & "<br>")
    rsRecordCount.Close
    set rsRecordCount = nothing
```

So - via response.write I get info about the occurrence. The problem arises
when I want to test the **cnt** variable

```
if cnt = 0 then
        response.write(".....<br>")
end if
```

just a simple test, the code stops execute here and I wonder why? I first thought cnt might work like a pointer pointing to a recordset and when setting it to null it would be error or undefined behaviour? But I've tried to comment out .Close and = nothing. The problem is still there.

Its really the cnt that is the prolem, If I use antoher variable - the code works again

```
if blablabla = 0 then
  response.write("it works now<br>")
end if
```

How do I get around this/what did I miss

thanks!!!

Comment: Any difference if you do `if CInt(cnt) = 0 then` ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - make an answer of it and I will accept :-) .. sorry didnt know typecast existed or was neccesary in asp since one do not even have to dim variables

Comment: I better not answer that, because i don't know __why__ that cast is needed. Maybe something to do with the concatenation when you do the response.write? can you please try it without the response.write and the cast? just to know.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - It is the cast that helps. Tried without the response with concat. and the typecast. The problem came back!. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

> I first thought cnt might work like a pointer pointing to a recordset

You were right in this assumption, but not 100% accurate. The default property of Recordset object returns a Field object, i.e. after this line:

```
cnt = rsRecordCount("TotalRecords")
```

The variable `cnt` is actually a Field object. Now you ask, why this line "works"?

```
response.write("cnt " & cnt & " id = " & id & "<br>")
```

That's because the Field object returns its Value property when being treated as a String.

However, when trying to compare to integer, VBScript fails to find any proper conversion and chokes.

There are two common ways to solve such a thing:

1. Convert the value to integer using CInt or CLng:

   ```
   cnt = CLng(rsRecordCount("TotalRecords"))
   ```

   Like the Response.Write above, this one first converts to String, then to Long. Profit.
2. Take the actual value, not the Field object:

   ```
   cnt = rsRecordCount.Fields("TotalRecords").Value
   ```

Personally, I think the second way is more elegant and readable. Both ways work. Good luck!

Comment: thanks - i'll look more into this later but i made a test of suggestion 2 and it did not work. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @java what is the type of the field in database?